# BigQuery auto-detect schema cause load of Google Drive CSV to fail

Tags: csv, google-api, google-bigquery

I've been using BigQuery for a while and load my data by fetching a CSV from an http address, uploading this to Google Drive using the Drive API, then attaching this to BigQuery using the BigQuery API.

I always specified auto-detect schema via the API and it has worked perfectly on a cron until March 16, 2017.

On March 16 it stopped working. The CSV still loads to Google Drive fine, but BigQuery won't pick it up.

I started troubleshooting by attempting to load the same CSV manually using the BigQuery UI, and noticed something strange: using auto-detect schema seems to prevent the loading of the CSV, because when I enter the schema manually it loads fine.

I thought maybe some rogue data might be the problem, but auto-detect schema isn't working for me now even with incredibly basic test tables, like...

id     name
1      Paul
2      Peter

Has anyone else found auto-detect schema suddenly stopped working.

Maybe some default setting has changed on the API?

Comment: There were some changes in auto-detect, but to trouble shoot your problem - can you provide the minimal repro case please

Comment: Thank you, Mosha. To reproduce create a CSV with two records, two columns (id and string) and a header row. Upload to Google Drive. Then add a dataset to BigQuery using the web UI, select Google Drive, CSV and paste the file sharing URL. Check Auto detect schema and it will fail. Enter the schema manually and it will succeed, though I have had problems subsequently querying the data in this case (can you try that too?)

Answer (score 0):

I could not get it to work either from GDrive today - 23 mar.

Note: first time ever using BigQuery/Google Cloud Storage.

I had a large CSV of bus stops 134MB.

Tried uploading it to GDrive but couldnt get it to import to big Query.

Just Tried Google Cloud Storage Bucket and it worked ok.